# Getting not a function error

Tags: lodash

I am using lodash 3.10.1 `trunc` method with `foreach` but getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.trunc is not a function
```

My code looks like:

```
_.forEach(myList, function(myListItem) {
        myListItem.text = _.trunc(myListItem.text, 10);
  });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could the problem be that you're using `_trunc` instead of `_.trunc()`?

Comment: Code corrected above. It wasn't that issue.

Comment: You are probably using underscore instead of lodash. Either that or `_.trunc` has been overwritten by a malicious third-party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trunc method in Version 3 changed to truncate in Version 4

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1930